# Jquery date picker with custom date

Tags: jquery, datapicker

I am trying to show date after 2 years and 3 months from today on JQuery UI 1.8.10 date picker. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.datepicker("[setDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate)", '+3m +2y');

Comment: This is not cross browser compatible.

Comment: It's very strange, but this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shehovn/UjZ3D/1/) works only with two strings.

Comment: Works with this code

$("#datepicker").datepicker({'setDate': '+3m +2y'});
$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', '+3m +2y');